# How to trim a meta key in query_posts in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

Okay. So I have a plugin that stores retrieved Amazon prices like this: $320.32. So it stores it as a string. The thing is I want to organize my products by price using a query_posts because the price is dynamic and changes.

So like for instance I want to take the price meta key amzn_LowestNewPrice and compare it to other values using BETWEEN and whatnot. For testing purposes, I'm just doing an EQUAL right now until I guess this to work.

The problem is that I need to first TRIM the meta key within Query_Posts and nothing I'm doing seems to work.

In this example, I use LTRIM on it to remove the $ and then use intval to make it a number. But it's not working.

```
<?php if (is_category('100-laptops-with-webcam')) { ?>

<?php query_posts(array('meta_key'=>'amzn_LowestNewPrice', 'meta_query'=>array(array('key'=>(intval(ltrim($post->amzn_LowestNewPrice,'$'))), 'compare'=>'=', 'type'=>'NUMERIC', 'value'=>179)))); ?>

<?php }; ?>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks so much!

Comment: `intval` will return an integer, not a float.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to the following. Unfortunately, it's still malfunctioning.

Comment: <?php query_posts(array('meta_key'=>'amzn_LowestNewPrice', 'meta_query'=>array(array('key'=>(floatval($post->amzn_LowestNewPrice)), 'compare'=>'>', 'type'=>'NUMERIC', 'value'=>359)))); ?>